# Opening an interstitial Ad with the help of AlarmManager and Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, interstitial

I want to open an interstitial ad when the app is not in the running mode and am trying to achieve it with the help of AlarmManager and Broadcast receiver, though broadcast receiver and AlarmManager are working. I check it with the help of toast message and the toast is appearing at the perfect time but interstitial ad is not appearing.

This is my code:

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdView mAdView;
    static InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        if (calendar.getTime().compareTo(new Date()) < 0) calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BroadcasReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

> Broadcast Receiver

```
public class BroadcasReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        final InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

        });
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                interstitialAd.show();

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 8000);
    }

}
```

> Manifest file

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".BroadcasReceiver"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

    </application>
```

Comment: You want to show Ads while the app is running in the background?

Comment: no..i want to show ad when the app is not even in the running mode and it can be done by an AlarmManager or JobScheduler but m not getting the result plzz help..

Comment: That is very intrusive and not recommend by the AdMob ad guidelines.

Comment: Yes bro i got it it is against the admob policy.